# GUI buttons in array

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compiler-errors, jbutton

I am working on a project and we are learning arrays. I need to create a GUI that has 12 buttons but need to be in an array. I am not finished with my code, so it may have errors because of that.

Where I am getting an error is on my

```
JButton[] = { new Jbutton("1"), ...};
```

the 2nd ] has a red line under it and gives me the error

```
Syntax error on token "]" VariableDeclaratorld expected after this token
```

Heres my code so far:

```
public class TextButtonsHW extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JButton[] buttons;  
private JTextArea textArea; 
private final int ENTER;    
private final int SPACE;    
private final int CLEAR;    

public TextButtonsHW(String title) {
    super(title); 
    JButton[] = { new JButton("A"), new JButton("B"), new JButton("C"),
                  new JButton("1"), new JButton("2"), new JButton("3"),
                  new JButton("X"), new JButton("Y"), new JButton("Z"),
                  new JButton("Enter"), new JButton("Space"), new JButton("Clear")};
    }
}
```

Comment: General tip.  Don't extend `JFrame`, just use an instance of a frame.

Answer (score 2):

```
JButton[] = {
```

Should be something like:

```
JButton[] buttonArray = {
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `buttons` as an instance variable:

```
private JButton[] buttons;
```

So you need to set that variable as so:

```
buttons = new JButton[] { new JButton("A") ...
```

Comment: That form of initializing an array is only valid when the array is declared at the same time as the variable is declared.

Comment: Whoops, missed that. Added initialization to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the name of the variable???

```
 JButton[] buttons = { new JButton("A"), new JButton("B"), new JButton("C"),
              new JButton("1"), new JButton("2"), new JButton("3"),
              new JButton("X"), new JButton("Y"), new JButton("Z"),
              new JButton("Enter"), new JButton("Space"), new JButton("Clear")};
```